# Can foribly killing a .net program lead to memory leak?

Tags: .net

From what I understand about .net, when I run an exe that was built in .net, CLR targeted by the exe is loaded into the process and then the exe itself. I know that the memory clean up is a part of the CLR's job.

So my question is if I start task manager and kill the process, would that mean that the CLR won't be able to run and clean up any references to the heap and thus causing memory leak? Or does the the operating system guarantee that any memory used by the process is reclaimed when the process is killed?

Comment: @FerretallicA: those will be torn down too when the process dies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** All memory reserved by a program is automatically freed by a modern operating system when the program closes.

Comment: Even by an operating system that's not modern.  This guarantee has been around for a *very* long time.  As long as programs have been crashing.  So, forever :)