# WPF event that occurs after application crash

Tags: c#, wpf, process, crash

Hello I got 2 question :

1) What event occours when the application crash? I need to invoke Dispose to resolve resources so how to do that when app crashes?

2) How to Dispose when we kill aplication procces through ALT+CTR+DELETE?

Comment: That's not a real question. Any event can crash an application if you don't catch it.

Comment: How to correct invoke Dispose on crash then ?

Comment: 1. you can use the UnhandledException event in Application
2. there is no way to do anything after the process has been killed

Comment: You wouldn't need to call Dispose on "leaked" resources because the OS will clean up your process space on an application crash.

Comment: If the App uses some external resources/devices there may be a requirement to call "Close"....

Comment: @VladimirGondarev Although it's good practice, it's not necessary at all. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038755/can-foribly-killing-a-net-program-lead-to-memory-leak and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149669/does-an-application-memory-leak-cause-an-operating-system-memory-leak

Handling shutdown gracefully to write things to a log file, for example, is a situation where your solution would come in handy.

Comment: @DavidN It can be necessary. I launch excel via COM, and if I don't explicitly dispose of the wrapper object, the excel process remains running after my app exits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) there are two event handlers:

```
Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;
```

All unhandled exceptions in UI thread.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

All other exceptions ...

2) there is no way to catch the situation when your app is killed through ALT+CTR+DELETE
The only Idea I can think of... create a watch dog app that checks the status of main app...